# Building native Opencv for Android with Eclipse gives "undefined reference to `cvCreateFileCapture'"

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm developing an app with native part which uses embedded OpenCV to extract frames from video file. So far I'm getting this error:

```
.../jni/ocv.c:12: undefined reference to `cvCreateFileCapture'
```

My Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ocv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ocv.c

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := armeabi
```

ocv.c:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>

jstring Java_com_ice_salvador_MainActivity_invokeNativeFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject javaThis) {
    IplImage* currFrame = 0;
    CvCapture* cap = 0;

    cap = cvCaptureFromFile("/mnt/sdcard/vvv.3gp"); //test video

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello from native code!");
}
```

I'm using OpenCV-2.4.3-android-sdk, Android NDK r8b, Eclipse Juno, Windows.

`IplImage`, `CvCapture` gets resolved and the code compiles if I remove the line with `cvCaptureFromFile` - so I assume I'm on the right way. I'm new to JNI and OpenCV. Appreciate your help! Thanks.

Comment: Have you linked with OpenCV library?

Comment: @luhb I'm not sure what should I do. Please explain.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android compiler, but for gcc there is a option `-l` to link external library. I think there should be something alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to leave my own question unanswered..

1) I've changed Android.mk to include OpenCV.mk from SDK and to include .so lib into the build:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include c:\dev\OpenCV-2.4.3-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := ocv
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ocv.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -Lc:\dev\OpenCV-2.4.3-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs\armeabi

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#LOCAL_PATH := /home/spatialite/jni
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libopencv_java
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libopencv_java.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

2) Copied libopencv_java.so to jni/ folder.

3) Changed java code to:

```
static {
  System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
  System.loadLibrary("ocv");
}
```

And the error has gone.

Comment: hey Artem: were you able to use cvCaptureFromFile() in JNI code after the above changes? Was it reading the video file successfully? I also need to do this…plz help me out…