# native opencv for android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I tried to integrate opencv library in my android project, so I followed this link: 
[Building native Opencv for Android with Eclipse gives "undefined reference to `cvCreateFileCapture'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353647/building-native-opencv-for-android-with-eclipse-gives-undefined-reference-to-c?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
but now I still have these errors:

> jni/DetectionBasedTracker.cpp:5:23: error: opencv/cv.h: No such file
>   or directory jni/DetectionBasedTracker.cpp:6:28: error:
>   opencv/highgui.h: No such file or directory

should I change the `application.mk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you reference OpenCV Library-2.4.4 in your project, in **Project Properties > Android > Library** ?

Have you included `<path_to_OpenCV4Android_sdk>/sdk/native/jni/include` in **Project Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > GNU C++**?